# div position with respect to parent parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html structure.
Please read "abcd" and "efgh" in the ids below as a random string that I generate and append it to give a unique id.

```
<div id="MainCanvas">
    <div id="canvas-1">
        <div id="MainDiv-abcd">
            <div id="Manvas-abcd">
            </div>
            <div id="Textdiv-abcd">
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div id="MainDiv-efgh">
            <div id="Manvas-efgh">
            </div>
            <div id="Textdiv-efgh">
            </div>  
        </div>
        ...there are more of the main Divs.
    </div>
    <div id="canvas-2">
    ....same structure as above.
    </div>    
</div>
```

My end goal is to iterate through all the spans and get some information regarding the spans.

My code right now is the following.

```
var counter = 1;
$('[id^="MainDiv-"]').each(function(i) {
        var spanId = this.id.replace("MainDiv-", "TextDiv-");
        if ($("#" + spanId).length) {
            if ($("#" + spanId).text().trim().length) {
                //here I get the canvas number which is a page in the application
                myPages[counter] = $(this).parent().attr("id").split("-")[1];
                //this is where I need to get the left and top position of the span
                //relative to the canvas
                counter = counter + 1;
            }
        }
    });
```

Open to changing the logic

Comment: What would you like to see as the result? How do you want the position notated?

Comment: changed my question to reflect the exact part of the code where I am stuck. Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the left and top offset of the parent and then subtract the left and top offset of the child you wish to get the position of.

Something like this:

```
var parent = $("#canvas"),
    child = $("#myspan"),
    parentTop = parent.offset().top,
    parentLeft = parent.offset().left,
    childTop = parent.offset().top,
    childLeft = parent.offset().left,
    childPosTop = parentTop - childTop,
    childPosLeft = parentLeft - childLeft;
```

`childPosTop` should contain the child's top offset relative to `canvas` and `childPosLeft` should contain its left offset relative to `canvas`.

Comment: I cannot directly apply the solution because I have lot of canvas divs with many "maindiv" within "canvas" divs. Each "maindiv" however has only 1 "manvas" and 1 "span". So i have to iterate through all maindivs like: $('[id^="MainDiv-"]').each(function(i) {

Comment: @PrasadGurla: You shouldn't have multiple `div`s with the same `id`.

Comment: @PrasadGurla, element id's should be unique within the document.

Comment: purmou and Jonathan: actually I simplified my code; each maindiv id is unique and each canvas id is unique as well. My main divs are like "maindiv-1" "maindiv-2" etc..therefore I iterate through all maindivs and locate the spans within the main div. Thereafter I need to know the position of the spans with respect to the canvas which is the parent of the maindiv

Comment: @PrasadGurla: In that case, iterating would be the appropriate thing to do. Then, instead of selecting those single `id`s, you could do `$(this).find("[id^='canvas-']")` and `$(this).find("[id^='myspan-']")`.

Comment: I finally used something similar to the above but my looping correctly as Purmou suggested.

Answer (score 0):

DOM nodes have a property `offsetParent` which is an object containing two keys: `x` and `y`.

Using JavaScript:

```
var mainPosition = document.getElementById("MainDiv").offsetParent;
alert(mainPosition.left + ", " + mainPosition.top);
```

But jquery has a wrapper to do this functionality in less-code-more-bloat fashion:

```
var mainPosition = $("#MainDiv").position();
alert(mainPosition.left + ", " + mainPosition.top);
```

Comment: The first example should be: `alert(mainPosition.offsetLeft + ", " + mainPosition.offsetTop);`, but there's still a problem, it alerts `0,0`.

Comment: `offsetParent()` is not doing what you think it does. It " returns a reference to the object which is the closest (nearest in the containment hierarchy) positioned containing element."

Comment: $("#MainDiv").position() gives the maindiv position relative to the canvas however I need the span position.